# How to pass the checkbox value to apex class method from visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a requirement in which when select the checkbox based on the value of checkbox i.e. true or false, I have to pass the value to Apex class method and based on the value of checkbox it should display an status images.
I have modified the code in VF page like this:

```
    j$('.voCheckbox').click(function() {
        j$('[id$=":selectedVerifiableOutcomeIdInput"]').val(j$(this).data("output"));
        j$('[id$=":currentStageInput"]').val(j$(this).data("stage"));
        completeActionJSCheck();
    });
<apex:actionFunction action="{!completeActionCheck}" name="completeActionJSCheck" >
     <apex:param name="v" value="" assignTo="{!myCheckbox}" /> 
</apex:actionFunction>
```

VF code for setting the image based on the value of checkbox:

```
    <label class="outcome-name">{!output.Name}:</label>
    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!currentOpportunity[output.FieldName__c] == true}">

    <input type="checkbox" class="voCheckbox"  Checked="Checked" Value="true" event="onselect" style="vertical-align: middle" data-outcome="{!outcome.Id}" enable="true"/>
    <i class=" green"></i>

    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel layout="none"  rendered="{!currentOpportunity[output.FieldName__c] == false}">
    <input type="checkbox" Checked="False" class="voCheckbox" event="onselect" style="vertical-align: middle" data-outcome="{!outcome.Id}" enable="true"/>
    <i class="fa fa-times red"></i>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

in the above code I have used to pass the value to the Boolean variable myCheckbox. But on UI when I select/disselect the checkbox then it thows and error. **"Value not of required type".**

in Apex class I have modified the below code :

```
public boolean myCheckbox {get; set;}
ActionResult result = ActionFactory.getInstance(selectedOutputId, oppId).execute(myCheckbox);
 checkActionResult(result);
```

Can somebody help me what I am missing here?
My target is i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not use an `actionFunction`, but rather `actionSupport`. Your checkbox will look something like this;

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!myCheckbox}>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!myApexFunction}" />
</apex:inputCheckbox>
```

In this case the checkbox will be automatically posted to the controller, so there's no need to pass it as a parameter. For reference; [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm) of the `actionSupport` element.

Comment: Hi @Lex  when I add the below code                            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!myCheckbox}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!completeActionCheck}" />
</apex:inputCheckbox> then it does not load the lage because in my case based on the value of true and false I am setting the images based on page load.I have added the image code In the question. please check

Comment: It seems to me you want to show a different image, based on the value of a chechbox. In that case you can still use `actionSupport`. I suggest you check the documentation, especially the part about the rerender attribute. You can also use it in conjunction with `actionRegion`, that would be helpful to you as well. Currently, the question is too unclear for me to provide more detailed code snippets.

Comment: the reason I am using actionfunction because it is under the <apex:form> that's why I have to use actionFunction in this case

Comment: An `actionSupport` can also be a child of a form. In fact, it has to be.